# Unbale to provide Authorization in api doc on Swagger hub for an api created on Laravel

Tags: laravel, authorization, swagger

Unable to provide Authorization in api doc on Swagger hub for an api created on Laravel. The laravel api uses Authorization Bearer token for which I'm doing documentation in Swagger Hub.

I have provided this code snippet in the swagger hub:

```
components:
     securitySchemes:
        bearerAuth:            # arbitrary name for the security scheme
          type: http
          scheme: bearer
          bearerFormat: JWT    # optional, arbitrary value for documentation purposes
    security:
      - bearerAuth: []
```

But I'm not getting any area to provide Authorization token. I'm new to Swagger hub , so unable to get solution for this. I thought it would provide me a textbox to provide Bearer token for Authorization, but it didn't. Need help and guide on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main requirement was to provide Authorization token for those api which require access token to check. So this is how I achieved.

Step 1: I removed this code from underneath components tag, as I don't need in all api.
security:
      - bearerAuth: []

Step 2: I putted the security tag within the api that needs access token.
    paths:
      /customer/segments/list/{venueId}:
     get:
       security:
         - bearerAuth: []

Step 3: Click on the save button if the button shows green (That means everything is fine)

Step 4: Click on documentation link , now you will find beside "Servers" label a button with name "Authorize" appears, now you need to click on it and put your access token and authorize it and then check test your Api in swagger. It will work.